# Excel Pivot Chart 2013 Multiple y-axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, axis

I used to use the pivot chart function in Access to overlay multiple sets of process variables to help understand relationships within my manufacturing process.   MS removed this function so now I'm forced to use the pivot chart function within excel but it is limited to 2 y-axis on a chart.   I'd like to have a 3rd and potentially 4th axis so I can overlay 4 unique process inputs that have very different scales.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you were able to use more than two vertical y-axis in a pivot chart before (I really would like to know how you did that). 
In relation to your question: I am wondering if scaling all the different scales of your 3 or 4 different processes to a common scale (for example to a percent scale, based on a maximum of 100%) could work for you.